# Who makes Dell's monitors?

Tags: display, external-display, lcd

I've done some research, consisting of checking various forums, but nobody seems to know.

What most people are saying is that it's very unlikely that Dell make their own LCDs, but they re-brand them. I've seen people considering that Samsung makes them, but nobody has shown any evidence of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BenQ make a lot of them.

When a new model is made - at least in the USA, a "FCC Declaration of Conformity" must be issued - stating that the screen complies with all required legislation and regulation.

For the 24056FPW monitor - the declaration ([link here](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/547355/Dell-2405fpw-Ultrasharp-24-Lcd-Monitor.html?page=66)) says it was made by BenQ

A little bit of googling has sent me to other pages which also list BenQ as manufacturer.

This isnt exactly an exhaustive list (I've tried a dozen or so monitor models, found declarations for 5, only 3 listed manufacturer and they all showed as BenQ) - but anecdotally at least - it suggests that a large number are manufactured by this company.

Hope this helps.